# ElectronJS, how verify if the user is logged in backend express session directly from the main process

Tags: javascript, express, electron, express-session

I cant find where i fail to check session with my electron app. My application is composed from a client site (main.js, preload.js and renderer (with some html files of course)), and a backend side in node.js with Express. All work fine between the too, excepte in one case: The verify if one user have a session in the backend for auto-login when the user start the App.This is the main.js (client side) file:

```
axios.get('http://localhost:9090/oauth/express-session-exist')
.then(response => {
  if (response.data.success) {
    const userIsConnected = store.get('user_publickey');
    if (userIsConnected) {
      if (store.get('user_active') == 'false') {
     mainWindow.loadFile('discovery.html');
      } else {
    mainWindow.loadFile('app.html');
      }
    } else {
      mainWindow.loadFile('oauth.html');
    }
   } else {
     const userIsConnected = store.get('user_publickey');
     if (userIsConnected) {
       store.clear();
     }
     mainWindow.loadFile('oauth.html');
   }
})
.catch(error => {
  console.error(error);
  mainWindow.loadFile('oauth.html');
});
```

And this is the backend fonction:

```
router.get('/express-session-exist', (req, res) => {
  if (req.session.user) {
    res.json({ success: true, data: req.session.user });
  } else {
    res.json({ success: false });
  }
});
```

And i am pretty sure the session is well created when i login my user for the first time with this backend function:

```
  // Login
  router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    try {
      const existingUser = await oauthModel.findUserByEmail(email);
      if (existingUser) {
        const passwordMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, existingUser.user_password);
        if (passwordMatch) {

          // Here, i created the express-session and put in value, then return the value to
          // Electron. A console.log() in the client show prefectly the data of the session.

          req.session.user = {
            publickey: existingUser.user_publickey,
            regenerativekey: existingUser.user_regenerativekey,
            email: existingUser.user_email,
            alias: existingUser.user_alias,
          };


          const toElectron = req.session.user;
          res.status(200).json({ success: true, message: 'user-logged-in', user: toElectron });
        } else {
          res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'wrong-password' });
        }
      } else {
        res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'cant-find-email' });
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(500).json({ success: false, message: 'ie500', error });
    }
  });
```

i dont know where to look at this point, AXIOS send request with the cookie so i dont know... Thank for reading me guys.

For informations this is my app.js:

```
  
  // app.js

  // Express setup
  const express = require('express');
  const session = require('express-session');
  const app = express();
  const port = 9090;

  // Chargement des modules
  const http = require('http');
  const server = http.createServer(app);
  const cors = require('cors');
  const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

  // Utiliser les sessions
  const sessionMiddleware = session({
    secret: 'mySecret',
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookie: {
      sameSite: 'Lax',
      maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 1000,
      secure: false // CARE PRODUCTION
    }
  });
  
  app.use(express.static('public'));
  app.use(cors({
    origin: ['http://localhost:9090'],
    credentials: true
  }));
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(bodyParser.json());
  app.use(sessionMiddleware);
  
  // Declaration Controllers
  const oauthController = require('./controllers/oauth');

  // Use Controllers
  app.use('/oauth', oauthController);

  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server listening :${port}`);
  });
```

I expect my route `/express-session-exist` to see that a session is created and return true. But she constantly return false.

Comment: I couldn`t see in the client code (electron) any state persistence related to auth. You need to save the login state in the local storage, so next time you open the window maybe the state will be saved.